# TELEGRAM: Possible to get messages from a private group if I have the group ID

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to forward messages from a group to a different chat. The chat does not allow me to add a bot, so I am trying to find a workaround other than utilizing a bot inside the group.

I did find a node Telegram Bot utility that would do it, but it requires that I know the msg.id, which I don't know if there is a way to find this without having a bot in the group to forward the messages.

```
bot.on('message',msg=>{
if(msg.chat.id===<source group id>)
    bot.forwardMessage(<your group id>, <source group id>, msg.id)
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** forward messages without a bot in group, even if you have the message id.

Think of it this way: if you could forward by group id and message id without join group, your privacy would be broken.